# When is the classifying space of a group/H-space rationally equivalent to a product of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, topological-groups, classifying-spaces, rational-homotopy-theory

The [MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/162001/rationalization-of-classifying-spaces) asks why the classifying space of a group is not necessarily rationally a product of Eilenberg–MacLane spaces.
I am looking for classes of examples of connected topological groups/connected associative H-spaces such that their classifying space happens to be rationally a product of Eilenberg–MacLane spaces. I'm the most interested in examples of groups that have an interesting action on a closed manifold.

So far I know that this holds for

- compact groups, because the cohomology ring of their classifying space is a polynomial ring
- Lie groups since they are homotopy equivalent to their maximal compact subgroup
- the identity component of the homotopy automorphisms of an aspherical space, because its classifying space is already an Eilenberg–MacLane space.

Comment: Someone explained to me, but I can't remember the details of, the orthography of [Mac Lane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saunders_Mac_Lane)'s name; he latterly went by Mac Lane, but originally by MacLane.  (Maybe that's all there is to the explanation, but I seem to remember more.)  But it was never Maclane, so I edited accordingly.

Comment: I believe it was for the sake of his first wife, Dorothy Jones, who found it easier to type it with a space.

Comment: @LSpice: you missed the title.

Comment: It will be true of any topological group (or even space) whose rational cohomology is a free associative, graded-commutative algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$. Simply choose a set of primitive generators to obtain a rational equivalence with a product of EM spaces. It's easy to verify that the obstructions for this to be an $A_\infty$-equivalence vanish. On the other hand, these cohomological conditions clearly need to hold for the outcome to be true. They're satisfied, for instance, by any group homotopy equivalent to a finite CW complex (e.g. any Lie group, as you recognise).

Comment: @Tyrone but does it suffice that the group has a free graded commutative cohomology ring over the rationals? Does this push down to the classifying space?

Comment: @RyanBudney, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466661/when-is-the-classifying-space-of-a-group-h-space-rationally-equivalent-to-a-prod#comment1211048_466661), thanks!  I see the author got it.

Comment: @ThorbenK the rational $A_\infty$-equivalence will push down to the classifying space.